# How to get the content in a tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I know that a tag wiki "is an editable page that briefly summarizes the topic of the tag and that may provide links to existing questions that are often useful to many people."

How can we find the tag wiki content? Is there a data dump available for downloading the tag wiki content?

Comment: SEDE or the data dump?

Comment: Any resource to know the tagWiki content.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice you were talking about the data dump. I don't know if that's available in the data dump.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to view the content in the tagWiki? How it is structured and it's format etc.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog no, OP is not talking about the data dump. They're looking for any way to get the content, the data dump is one of them. SEDE is much easier to use. The answer to the duplicate contains fully working example.